# Unable to get response from Microsoft Graph API endpoint

Tags: azure, oauth, microsoft-graph-api, credentials

I set up a new Application in microsoft azure and got the admin to consent application permissions for this app ( `files.ReadWriteAll`). I am able to get the `access_token` through POSTMAN. I am trying to get drive information using this endpoint

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}
```

But I get an error response :-

```
{ "error": { "code": "AccessDenied", "message": "Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.", "innerError": { "request-id": "905c7701-8b89-4711-9204-b00c4a09a921", "date": "2019-03-28T15:56:29" } } }
```

I used this link to get info on my access token. 
http://jwt.calebb.net/

`Files.Readwrite` permissions don't seem to be listed anywhere in the info ( not sure why) . The azure site shows that consent was granted.

Azure permissions set up for my app:
[image: Azure permissions set up for my app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the steps as below.

1. Register your app following [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-register-app-v2), and Grant permissions.
2. get access token like this.

[image]

3. Check the token

[image]

4. Call graph api
   [image]